# dump($_ENV) not working in laravel version 7x

Tags: laravel

Here the code

**Controller** :

```
public function index()
{
        dump($_ENV);
}
```

**Route** :

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

I can't display env file in the screen

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `$_ENV` is a php function what you want to get from it ? https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

Comment: Do u mean .env file of laravel application ?

Comment: yes,  I get empty string

Comment: Can you share more details? What makes you think that something is not working? Maybe there's nothing within `$_ENV`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your $_ENV array is mysteriously empty, but you still see the variables when calling getenv() or in your phpinfo(), check your http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order ini setting to ensure it includes "E" in the string.

Answer (score 0):

*Try:*

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

*chek:*

```
{{ env('APP.ENV') }}
```

Comment: i check it, it's return null

Comment: try as well php artisan route:clear and php artsian view:clear check {{ env('APP.ENV'),'test' }}

Answer (score 0):

your doing things in wrong way try this

```
env('APP_ENV');
getenv('APP_ENV');
```

if your using cache then you can access the value from config like this .

```
config('app.env');
```

or using facede

```
Config::get('app.env');
```